# Print all lines greater than a timestamp in linux ( read log file)

Tags: awk

Print all lines greater than a timestamp in linux ( read log file)

`"awk -v d1="$(date --date="-10 min" "+<%_d/%m/%Y, %-I:%M")" -v d2="$(date "+<%_d/%m/%Y, %-I:%M")" '$0 > d1 && $0 < d2 || $0 ~ d2' logfile"`

### result

```
27/07/2022, 11:14:23,132 Õ GST Error
27/07/2022, 11:14:23,134 Õ GST Error
27/07/2022, 11:14:23,175 Õ GST Error
27/07/2022, 11:14:23,176 Õ GST Error
```

### expected result

```
27/07/2022, 11:14:23,132 Õ GST Error
some text 
some text 
27/07/2022, 11:14:23,134 Õ GST Error
27/07/2022, 11:14:23,175 Õ GST Error
some text 
some text 
27/07/2022, 11:14:23,176 Õ GST Error
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts. Please do edit your question to make your samples of input and expected output more clear so that its easy for us to understand, thank you.

Comment: input a log file , it contains 1000 of lines , some lines start with timestamp some are not..
so i am trying to get last 10 minutes of entry in the logfile..

used the below command , got the result , but the lines between date/timetsamp missing.

"awk -v d1="$(date --date="-10 min" "+<%_d/%m/%Y, %-I:%M")" -v d2="$(date "+<%_d/%m/%Y, %-I:%M")" '$0 > d1 && $0 < d2 || $0 ~ d2' logfile"

I need the text or lines between the date lines as well.

hope the question is clear

Comment: You show result and expected result but no sample input we could test a potential solution against to see if we get the expected result. Please [edit] your question to add the missing sample input.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the timestamps in the logfile are sorted in ascending order
(older first, newer last), would you please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -v d1="$(date --date="-10 min" "+%Y/%m/%d, %T,%3N")" '
    # rearrange the date string in "yyyy/mm/dd" order
    function rearrange(str,   a) {
        sub(/,$/, "", str)
        split(str, a, /\//)
        return sprintf("%s/%s/%s", a[3], a[2], a[1])
    }

    f {print; next}                     # if flag is set, print the line
    /^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/ {   # looks like a timestamp line
        d = rearrange($1) ", " $2       # "d" is the rearranged timestamp
        if (d > d1) {                   # if the timestamp is newer than "d1"
            f = 1                       # set the flag
            print
        }
    }
' logfile
```

- You need to rearrange the `date` field in `yyyy/mm/dd` order for string comparison.
  The function `rearrange` does it.
- You need to pass the date string `d1` *only*, because comparison with
  `d2` (now) will be meaningless.
- Once the flag `f` is set, no more comparisons are needed thereafter, as the lines below are assured to be newer.

**[Edit]**
Assuming the log is updated everyday and almost every seconds, would you please try the efficient version:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -v d1="$(date --date="-10 min" "+%d/%m/%Y, %T,%3N")" '
    f {print; next}                     # if flag is set, print the line
    d1 ~ $1 {                           # the days match
        if ($1 " " $2 > d1) {           # the time is newer than d1
            f = 1                       # set the flag
            print
        }
    }
' logfile
```

Please note this version may fail if `d1` is almost midnight such as `27/07/2022, 23:59:59.999`
and no timestamps later than that on the same day are found.

Comment: Thanks for the help @tshiono.

My string compariosn work fine and dont want to do more opertaions on the logfiles entries as , per minutes 1000+ lines generating and i need to process around 10 file at same time, so more processing on the files will take time...

my only concern is , i want to print the lines ( lines not statring with the date format) in the output

Comment: I've updated my answer with an efficient version. BTW I'm afraid your string comparison may fail with the timestamps across the
months. For instance, if
`d1` is `30/06/2022, 23:50:00,000` and
`d2` is `01/07/2022, 00:00:00,000`, then no lines will be printed.

Comment: Good idea on that first script setting a flag when the criteria is met so you don't have to test it again for the rest of the input.

Comment: As you identified in your comment, that second script can;t work.

Comment: Thank you so much to both Ed Morton and tshiono  ..  
I will test your suggestions and will feedback ...

Answer (score 2):

To print all lines greater than a timestamp from 10 mins earlier from a log file formatted as you show would be this, using any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk -v tgtTime="$(date --date='-10 min' +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')" '
    match($0,"^([0-9]{1,2}/){2}[0-9]{4}, ([0-9]{1,2}:){2}[0-9]{1,2},") {
        split(substr($0,1,RLENGTH),t,"[/, :]+")
        curTime = sprintf("%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d",t[3],t[2],t[1],t[4],t[5],t[6])
    }
    curTime >= tgtTime
' file
```

Comment: So this script will work in all timestamp scenarios ? Also , our log files we are trying to read are ~ 50 to 100 MB size ( oracle weblogic application logs)

Comment: It'll work with timestamps formatted as you provided for us to test with. If you have some other formats of timestamp that you haven't shared with us then I wouldn't expect it to work with those. You should mention the size of your log file in your question if you feel it's relevant, but my script is reading 1 line at a time and using almost no memory no matter how large your input file is and will be very fast.